# boost maximum flow doesn't compile when template directedgraph is used?

Tags: c++, graph, boost, max-flow

I want to calc a max flow with the boost graph libary.
UPDATE Due to request here is the full code:+

#### CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PPINetwork.h"
#include <boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/read_dimacs.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>

#include "interactions.h"


using namespace std;

void PPINetwork::addEdge(string &p1, string &p2, double w){
 Vertex s,e;
 if(g.vertex(p1)==g.null_vertex()){
   s = g.add_vertex(p1);
   g.graph()[s].name = p1;
 }
 else
   s = g.vertex(p1);
 if(g.vertex(p2)==g.null_vertex()){
   e = g.add_vertex(p2);
   g.graph()[e].name = p2;
 }
 else
   e = g.vertex(p2);

 g.graph().add_edge(s,e,{1-w,w});

}

void PPINetwork::readNetwork(ifstream &ppin_file) {

 // Create a graph object
 string line;
 std::getline(ppin_file, line); //skip header
 while (std::getline(ppin_file, line)) {
 std::istringstream iss(line);
 string p1, p2;
 float w;
 if (!(iss >> p1 >> p2 >> w)) {
  throw invalid_argument("line has wrong formaat\n" + line);
 } // error
 addEdge(p1,p2,w);
}
cout << "read " << boost::num_edges(g) << " Edges" << std::endl;
}

PPINetwork::PPINetwork(ifstream &file) {
 readNetwork(file);
}

double PPINetwork::maxflow(vector<string> srcs,vector<string> sinks) {
//add common src and sink
 vector<string> src_verticies;
 vector<string> sink_verticies;
 //filter out non existing verticies
 for (string s: srcs) {
   Vertex src_v = g.vertex(s);
   if (src_v != g.null_vertex())
    src_verticies.push_back(s);
   }
  for (string s: sinks) {
   Vertex sink_v = g.vertex(s);
  if (sink_v != g.null_vertex())
   sink_verticies.push_back(s);
 }
 double max_double = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
 Vertex new_src = g.add_vertex("new_src");
 Vertex new_sink = g.add_vertex("new_sink");
 string ssrc = "new_src";
 string ssink = "new_sink";
 // add common sink and src
 for (string &s : src_verticies) {
  addEdge(ssrc, s, max_double);
 }
 for (string &s : src_verticies) {
  addEdge(s, ssink, max_double);
 }
 auto capacity = boost::get(boost::edge_capacity, g);
 auto reverse  = boost::get(boost::edge_reverse, g);
 auto residcap = boost::get(boost::edge_residual_capacity, g);
 auto indexmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);

 double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, new_src, new_sink,capacity,residcap, reverse, indexmap);
}

PPINetwork::PPINetwork() {

}
```

#### H-File:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_PPINETWORK_H
#define UNTITLED_PPINETWORK_H

#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/undirected_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/directed_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/labeled_graph.hpp>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
struct VertexProperty
{
 string name;
};
 typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Traits;
 typedef boost::property<boost::edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor> rev;
 typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double,
  boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, double,
   boost::property<boost::edge_residual_capacity_t, long,
    rev > > > EdgeDesc;
 typedef boost::labeled_graph<boost::directed_graph<VertexProperty,EdgeDesc>,std::string> diGraph;
 typedef unordered_map<string,unordered_map<string,double>> ssf_map;
 typedef  boost::graph_traits<diGraph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
 typedef boost::graph_traits < diGraph >::edge_descriptor Edge;

class PPINetwork {
 public:
  PPINetwork();
  PPINetwork(ifstream &ppin_file);
  void addEdge(string &p1, string &p2, double w);
  double maxflow(vector<string> srcs,vector<string> sinks);


 private:
  void readNetwork(ifstream &ppin_file);
 diGraph g;
};

#endif //UNTITLED_PPINETWORK_H
```

When i add the line:

```
double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, new_src,new_sink,capacity,residcap, reverse, indexmap);}
```

it doesn't compile although i provided all the necessary arguments. I get long unreadable error message, but i think the problem is related to the graph type. Errors look like this:

> error: conversion from 'boost::detail::edge_desc_impl boost::directed_tag, long long unsigned int' to non-scalar type 
>    boost::detail::push_relabel boost::labeled_graph boost::directed_graph VertexProperty.......

had to remove the <,> signs to make stackoverflows cite function accept the error

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `new_src` and `new_sink` please? We are missing a fair bit of context in order to be able to help.

Comment: Gosh. You could just show the code that doesn't compile. This is _bound_ to be one to the v-v-FAQ and it would be so convenient if we could just show you

Comment: i added the code

Comment: I did a bit of research and found out that directed_graph class template seems to be incompatible with the maximum flow algorithms. Can someone confirm that? if i use the adjacency_list template compilation does not fail

Comment: also when i run the push_relabel_max_flow function i get segmentation faults, what is wrong with my code, what else do i need to provide for the algorithm to work?